# Phonegap app NSCalendarsUsageDescription error:This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description

Tags: ios, cordova, app-store-connect, cordova-plugins, itunes-store

I have phonegap app.I want to upgrade it and I add admob as described here( http://yazilimsozluk.com/phonegap-uygulamaya-admob-ekleme )

I add config.xml to this plugin

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-simple" version="3.3.4" source="npm"/>
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
```

and add ads code to my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDeviceReady() {


        initAd();

    }
    function initAd(){
        if ( window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob ) {
            var ad_units = {
                ios : {
                    banner: 
....
```

and then upload my app to build.phonegap...It build it successful.I add .apk to google play and it works very well.Then I try to upload .ipa to apple store but with application loader it give that error.I don't use any  NSCalendarsUsageDescription  plugin.I don't need any permission for this.Where this come?Why it give that error ?Is admob or cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin include  NSCalendarsUsageDescription  ?How can I handle this?

**Missing Info.plist key - This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

Comment: this should help you, you need to add that for admob https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/UmeVUDrcDaw/HIXR0kjUAgAJ

Comment: Thank,but I have not xcode...I write code in notepad++  there is no Info.plist file....How can I add this to confix.xml as a plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link updating to the latest version of the framework should help. The plugin you are using depends on [this plugin](https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-admob-sdklibs) which includes GoogleMobileAds.framework. It hasn't been updated in two years though.

You can try to fix this by forking both plugins and installing them using git urls. For `cordova-plugin-admob-simple` you should remove the line `<dependency id="cordova-admob-sdklibs"/>` and for the sdklibs plugin, update the GoogleMobileAds.framework. You could also file an issue or pull request to use the latest library.

Comment: Should I change admob-simple to cordova-plugin-admob-x which use lastest sdk ?  https://www.npmjs.com/~cupertino

Comment: I haven't used either of them but it wouldn't hurt to try. It may be better in the long run to use a plugin that stays up to date instead of maintaining your own fork